# Я скачал GrabzIt через PyCharm community edition и я хочу конвертировать HTML файл в PNG файл. Но здесь ошибка в этой строке

Tags: python

```
File "C:\Users\ameli\PycharmProjects\MyProject\main.py", line 31, in on_message
    grabzIt = grab.GrabzItClient("ZGU3ZjE0MDFjNDcwNDcyYzg4N2JiMmY3NjhkZDBkYTM=", "P2c/Pz9pMz8/eXQ/CFk8P1Y/XE4zP2p8KE5ZPz8/Py0=")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.
```

Вот такую ошибку выдаёт. Помогите решить данную проблему. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, так как на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском

Comment: Судя по ошибке, GrabzItClient - это модуль, а не класс или функция. Значит импортируете (или вызываете) неправильно. Сверьтесь с примером, на основе которого свой код пишете.